# Heroku app crashing, error H10, bad file descriptor in open.rb (Errno::EBADF)

Tags: ruby, heroku

Error in deploying to heroku

2014-09-29T10:54:02.551390+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/1.9.1/io/open.rb:2:in `open'
2014-09-29T10:54:02.551375+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/1.9.1/io/open.rb:2:in`close': Bad file descriptor - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/1.9.1/io/open.rb (Errno::EBADF)

The error starts from here, yet no changes were made to the version numbers. The code change was just a change to the styling in the widget, so it can't be that.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here was on heroku's side, was using ruby 2.0.0 and they changed the patch version from p481 to p576 (https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/529)

I'm not sure what the error is with this patch, but I resolved the problem by specifying the ruby version in the gemfile (I was using 2.1.2 locally so just specified this)

ruby '2.1.2'

Comment: I've changed the version of ruby and now works fine, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[Dashing does not run on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167440/dashing-does-not-run-on-heroku) gave me another answer - just run `bundle update backports`.